# how to get response from twilio call and display that in browser

Tags: python, twilio

If a client presses any button during the call, the response should be displayed in the browser window. Is this kind of option available in Twilio?

Comment: Why don't you ask twilio support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**TwiML™**](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) for Dialing call. It have features like `<Gather>` which is used to gather user input during the call.

The caller enters digits followed by a # symbol or 5 seconds of silence. Twilio will submit those digits in a `POST` request back to the URL hosting your **TwiML**. This `POST` request is your webhhok like thing you can define endpoint to be used for posting user input to your web server. For more information on Twilio Gather visit https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather